# выдает ошибку : illegal start of expression - public static int stepen (int a, int n){ и еще одну : illegal start of type else { в чем дело?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("выберете умножение или возведение в степень");
        String w = "возвeдение в степень";
        Scanner inn = new Scanner (System.in);
     String w = inn.nextString();
     if (w) {
            System.out.println("введите показатель степени");
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
     int n = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("введите число");
     int a = in.nextInt();
         int resultcomp = stepen(a, n); 
          System.out.println ("результат = " + resultcomp);
}           
public static int stepen (int a, int n){
        int result = 1;
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
            result *=a; 
            return result;
}
else {  
System.out.println ("введите первый множитель");
Scanner h = new Scanner (System.in);
int mnoj = h.nextInt ();
System.out.println("введите второй множитель");
int mnoj2 = h.nextInt();
int resultcomp2 = umnojenie (mnoj, mnoj2);
System.out.println ( "результат = " + resultcomp2);
}
public static int umnojenie ( int mnoj, int mnoj2 ) {
        int result1 = mnoj * mnoj2;
        return result1;
    }           
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Не хватает закрывающих фигурных скобок в методах `main` и `stepen`. Отформатируйте как следует код, и сами увидите.